# Doubt regarding collision map

Tags: ros, collision-map

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i have a few doubts regarding the collision map -

1. is it possible to use our own cloud data as a collision map?
2. is there a possibility to identify clusters/cloud within the collision map as objects so that my arm does not consider those as collisions and can go near it..

i know these features should be present i am still looking for them, till then if any1 of you has any idea do let me know.

Thank you :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11812/doubt-regarding-collision-map/) by [Navam](https://answers.ros.org/users/1078/navam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2011-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Yes
2. You will have to do the work yourself such as clustering deciding what is to be avoided etc. And then publish on a separate topic to populate the collision map.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0